# Повторение операции Python

Tags: python, циклы

В общем, вот мой код:

```
person = {'name' : {'last_name': 'Иванов', 'first_name': 'Иван', 'middle_name': 'Иванович'}, 'address': ['г. Москва', 'ул. Пушкина д. 1337', 'кв.228'], 'phone': {'home_phone': '14-48', 'mobile_phone': 'None'}}
choose = int(input('Выберите пункт из списка: \n 1. Имя \n 2. Фамилия \n 3. Отчество \n 4. Адресс \n 5. Домашний телефон \n 6. Мобильный телефон \n 7. Завершить \n'))
if choose == 1:
    print(person['name']['first_name'])
elif choose == 2:
    print(person['name']['last_name'])
elif choose == 3:
    print(person['name']['middle_name'])
elif choose == 4:
    print(person['address'])
elif choose == 5:
    print(person['phone']['home_phone'])
elif choose == 6:
    print(person['phone']['mobile_phone'])
elif choose == 7:
    print('Вы успешно завершили операцию!')
else: 
    print('Вы ввели неверное значение, повторите процедуру ещё раз')
```

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы код повторился один раз, пока choose !=7
То есть, если я ввожу любое значение кроме 7, код срабатывал и выводил нужную мне информацию (это все уже есть в коде) и код повторялся ещё раз, а если я задал значение 7, то код завершался.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Поместите условия в бесконечный цикл и добавьте возможность выхода из цикла при нажатии 7 с помощью `break`

```
person = {'name' : {'last_name': 'Кругликов', 'first_name': 'Андрей', 'middle_name': 'Андреевич'}, 'address': ['г. Андрюшки', 'ул. Пушкина д. 1337', 'кв.228'], 'phone': {'home_phone': '14-48', 'mobile_phone': 'None'}}

while True:
    choose = int(input('Выберите пункт из списка: \n 1. Имя \n 2. Фамилия \n 3. Отчество \n 4. Адресс \n 5. Домашний телефон \n 6. Мобильный телефон \n 7. Завершить \n'))

    if choose == 1:
        print(person['name']['first_name'])
    elif choose == 2:
        print(person['name']['last_name'])
    elif choose == 3:
        print(person['name']['middle_name'])
    elif choose == 4:
        print(person['address'])
    elif choose == 5:
        print(person['phone']['home_phone'])
    elif choose == 6:
        print(person['phone']['mobile_phone'])
    elif choose == 7:
        print('Вы успешно завершили операцию!')
        break
    else: 
        print('Вы ввели неверное значение, повторите процедуру ещё раз')
```

Comment: Зачем добавлять возможность выхода из цикла при нажатии 7 через break, если нужно просто в качестве условия для цикла выставить "пока choose не станет равна 7"?

Comment: Спасибо, это мне и нужно было!

Comment: @Эникейщик в вопросе есть "и код повторялся ещё раз, а если я задал значение 7, то код завершался." думаю, все сделано верно.

Comment: Можно и умножение выполнять в цикле сложением. Тоже типа "верно".

Comment: @Эникейщик значение переменной `choose` должно  присваиваться внутри цикла, если в качестве условия цикла указать проверку `choose`, то будет доступ к переменной, которой еще не существует.

Comment: @Andrey Если не создать, то не существует, верно.

Comment: @Эникейщик Да, верно. Я решил не создавать.